# Can i get continuity in the inputs of Op Amp (TL072)

Tags: operational-amplifier, audio, clock, input-impedance

[image]
[image]

Hello everyone,

I have 1 doubt, i made in a protoboard an audio sequencer to provide CV(control voltage). The circuit is from [MFOS][3]. What happen is that the inputs of the op amp (TL072) are giving continuity with the multimeter, and i suppose that the impedance should be very high, like an ideal Op Amp have infinitive impedance. I know that im not in the ideal world. Like so,i should get an integration on the 1st configuration(U3:A) and it will rise until at least 8volts to trigger the comparator of U3:B to +12v, it will send a current to open the jfet and reset the integrator again, in that time resets too the comparator to -12. And it will stay like that, is a clock, until i stop with a Flip-Flop type D. The potenciometer RV1 gives a faster or slower rise on the integrator. What is suppose to have in the inverter input of U3:A is 1volt with the clock stopped, and should rise with the clock on. My doubt is i only get a few milivolts less that the ground, 1 or so. They are almost equal. I test everything tons of times and nothing. I get continuity with the multimeter between the non-inverter and the inverter inputs. When i take out the chip(op amp) gives the right reading on the dip socket. I already try with other ones(tl072) and is the same, and they work proper in other parts of the circuit. I really dont know what to do. I'm missing something? can you give me any help please?
Thx so much,

MAINTAB=SYNTHDIY&PROJARG=TENSTEPSEQUENCER/TENSTEPSEQUENCER.php&VPW=1270&VPH=761

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE, please be more specific about your question. Review http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask "Can you give me help" is not a good question, Thanks

Comment: Are you attempting to measure the resistance between op-amp inputs with the op-amp in-circuit?

Answer (score 1):

"Resistance" between the inputs to a monolithic op-amp is UNDEFINED. It plays no significant role in circuit design for an op-amp stage. Attempting to measure it will provide no useful information.

If you are having a problem with your U3A stage, suggest replacing Q11 with a suitable resistor to confirm whether the problem is the U3A area, or whether the problem is with Q11 and whatever is driving it (not shown in your diagram).

Comment: Ok thx guys! I will try and change with a resistor on the Q11 and see what happens. Its strange, because the voltages are right in all the places but the U3:A op amp doesnt do the ramp, stays at few milivolts. It should ramp untl 8v to trigger the U3:B stage. 
I will read more and check again the board.
In a few days i tell something! Have a nice weeks guys, ;)

Comment: I already put 1 resistor of 10k and the clock worked. Too fast by the way. I simulate firts in LTSpice and gave the same result as in simulation. I put again the Jfet BF245b and didnt work again. This is blowing my mind. if was from the jfet it didnt latch, but it did that. This integrator is killing me. I really dont know what to say. I check the continuity of that track and its normal. My god!
The integrator is driving the other scheme that i put. Page 1 of 3.

Answer (score 1):

> What is suppose to have in the inverter input of U3:A is 1volt with
>   the clock stopped

With the clock stopped (via a driving voltage through D17) U3A acts as an inverter with zero (or very, very small negative gain). This is because the JFET is activated to a low on-resistance.

Now that the op-amp is operating in linear mode, what appears on the -Vin is pretty much what voltage you have on +Vin i.e. 0V and NOT -1V.

> I get continuity with the multimeter between the non-inverter and the
>   inverter inputs.

In this state (clock stopped, power and JFET on) the op-amp is forcing the two inputs to have the same voltage hence you will see continuity. Nothing wrong here.

My advice is that if the thing doesn't work it's unlikely to be the integrator.

Comment: Thx so much for the replys, Richard and Andy.;) Your ideas help a lot!
I already change the schematic image. Is the 2part of 3. Now this stage is complete.
I noticed that should be normal to have continuity between the inputs of U3: A because the voltage is very close to 0, only a few millivolts. I confess that I am not expert but I know some things. lol, I had forgotten that the op amp power inputs to have the closest possible tension. 
the jfet (n-channel) is working because when activating the Q input of the flip flop with + 12v the gate have about -2V.

Comment: If i activate the not-Q, the gate has more or less 600mV. How Q11 reacts to flip flop and latch is good,
 now Richard, you suggested put a resistance instead of Q11 to test it? where? which of the Q11 entries let loose, 
drain or source?

Comment: Andy: Now that the op-amp is operating in linear mode, 
what appears on the Vin is pretty much what you have voltage on + Vin i.e. 0V and NOT -1V.
I explaine me wrong, the entry of U3: A has -1v without the Amp Op,
 I refer to the inverting input in the socket without the TL072. With the chip (TL072) have 10 mvolts.
ANy suggestions?

Comment: There is nothing I can suggest - it appears to be working as shown in the schematic and you appear to want something else BUT, I don't know what that is.

Comment: Thx anyway Andy! ;) Just one thing, i disconnect the not-Q 4013(flip flop D) from d17 and it worked. It runned smoothly but it dont stop. When i connect again the not-Q to d17(diode) it wont work. Strange. With the 12 volts from not-Q it dont run but without the 12 volts works. Any idea?
Thx in advance, ;)